# How to select the records until I achieve a value without changing the original value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with the following structure:

[image]

I want to select the records from table1 until I reach the corresponding record amount from table2 without changing the quantity. Example: Order of productId 232 with 160 units, I have to search in table1 until I fill 160 and the last record must be complete, that is, instead of 2 lines with 60 units and the third one with 40, I need the 3 to come with 60, so that I arrive at the order quantity without changing the original quantity. The result would look like this:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum:

```
select t2.*, t1.*
from (select t1.*, sum(qty) over (partition by product_id order by reg) as running_qty
      from table1 t1 
     ) t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.product = t2.product
where running_qty - qty < t2.order_qty
```